# Задача «Вася строит дом»

Tags: python, python-3.x, координаты

Всем здравствуйте! Только начал изучать Python. Не могу решить одну задачу:

> Мальчик Вася живёт на координатной прямой. На этот прямой в точке 
>   располагается школа, а в точке  — любимый Васин компьютерный клуб.
>   Также в точках `…, −, 0, , …, ⋅, …,` где  — произвольное
>   целое число, а  — чётное натуральное число, расположены киоски с
>   мороженым.
>
> Вася хочет построить дом в некоторой точке с целой
>   координатой. При этом ему хочется, чтобы расстояние от дома до школы и
>   от дома до компьютерного клуба было одинаковым.
>
> Если это вдруг
>   невозможно, то он хочет, чтобы сумма этих расстояний была как можно
>   меньше, а также, чтобы расстояния отличались как можно меньше друг от
>   друга.
>
> Если под Васин дом подходит несколько вариантов точек, то он
>   выберет ту, расстояние от которой до ближайшего киоска с мороженым
>   минимально.
>
> Помогите Васе выбрать точку, где строить дом, а также
>   выведите расстояние до ближайшего киоска с мороженым.

**Входные данные:**
В единственной строке входных данных заданы три числа — ,  и . Гарантируется, что  и  — целые числа, по модулю не превышающие `2⋅10**9`, `≠`.  — чётное натуральное число, `2 ≤  ≤ 2⋅10**9`.

**Выходные данные:**
В единственной строке выходных данных выведите два целых числа — координату точки, где Васе необходимо построить дом и расстояние до ближайшего киоска с мороженым.

**Примеры:**
*Ввод 1:*

```
1 5 4
```

*Вывод 1:*

```
3 1
```

*Ввод 2:*

```
1 6 4
```

*Вывод 2:*

```
4 0
```

**Пояснения к примерам 1 и 2:**
[image: **Пояснение к примерам:**]

Я многократно пытался решить задачу, но все попытки тщетны: моё решение помечается как неверное (`Программа выдаёт неверный ответ`). Хотя я сам проверял свою программу на около десятке примеров, и всё получалось как надо. **Мой код:**

```
A,B,d = map(int, input().split())

if (A+B) % 2 == 0:
    C = (A+B)//2
elif (A+B) % 2 == 1:
    C = (A+B)//2
    if C%d == 0:
        C = (A+B)//2
    elif ((A+B)//2 + (A+B)%2)%d == 0:
        C = (A+B)//2 + (A+B)%2
    elif C%d < (C+(A+B)%2)%d:
        C = (A+B)//2 + (A+B)%2
    else:
        C = (A+B)//2

n = C%d

if n < d/2:
    s = n
else:
    s = d-n

print(C, s)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. Я уже просто сбился с толку в решении этой задачи…

Comment: не рассмотрен второй вариант для нечётной суммы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этой задаче вижу следующие тонкости:

1. Не сказано, что дом обязательно должен быть между школой и клубом, соответственно возможен вариант, когда школа и клуб рядом, а дом надо ставить справа или слева от них. Например, в комбинации `4 5 7` дом можно поставить на  `3` и на `6`. От `3` расстояние до ближайшего киоска с мороженым (находится в 0) равно 3, от `6` расстояние до ближайшего (находится в 7) равно 1. Следовательно выбираем `6`.
2. Нужно учитывать возможную разницу в знаках:

   - в случае `1 5 4` расстояние = `4`.
   - в случае `-1 5 4` расстояние = `6`.

#### Решение

```
def find_house_place():
    school, club, ice_interval = map(int, input().split())

    school_club_dist = abs(school - club)

    if school_club_dist > 1:
        first = school_club_dist // 2
        second = school_club_dist - first
    else:
        first = -1
        second = 2 

    leftest_point = min(school, club)

    point_1 = leftest_point + first
    point_2 = leftest_point + second

    remainder_1 = point_1 % ice_interval
    remainder_2 = point_2 % ice_interval

    dist_to_ice_1 = min(remainder_1, ice_interval - remainder_1)
    dist_to_ice_2 = min(remainder_2, ice_interval - remainder_2)

    res = (point_1, dist_to_ice_1) if dist_to_ice_1 <= dist_to_ice_2 else (point_2, dist_to_ice_2)

    print(res[0], res[1])
```

---

#### Тестирование

```
for _ in range(5):
    find_house_place()
```

**input.txt**

```
1 5 4 
1 6 4 
0 101 70
-51 20 5 
4 5 7
```

**Output**

```
3 1
4 0
51 19
-15 0
6 1
```

Answer (score 4):

В существующем решении не учтено это условие задачи:

> Если под Васин дом подходит несколько вариантов точек, то он выберет ту, расстояние от которой до ближайшего киоска с мороженым минимально.

Нужно рассмотреть оба потенциальных места дома, и выбрать то, которое ближе к киоску с мороженным.

Тут еще видно, что при некоторых вариантах входных данных (A=1, B=2, d=1) оба варианта размещения дома будут на одинаковом расстоянии от киоска. Так что в таких случаях задача допускает несколько правильных решений.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я написал код по Вашему решению, но почему-то моё решение не принимается. Не пойму, где я допустил ошибку. Я обновил свой вопрос, добавив в него новый код. Не подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Я изменил ответ, чтобы он соответствовал новому вопросу.

Comment: Roman Konoval, я учёл Ваши рекомендации и сильно переработал своё решение, но моё решение до сих пор отмечается, как неверное. Пожалуйста, помогите снова найти ошибку. У меня просто не получается… Я изменил вопрос, добавив новый код.

Answer (score 2):

Что-нибудь вроде такого, с учётом нечетной суммы и отрицательных чисел:

```
A,B,d = map(int, input().split())
summ = A + B
C = summ // 2
D = C % d
s = min(D, d - D)
if summ % 2:
    C2 = (summ + 1) // 2 if summ >= 0 else (summ - 1) // 2
    D = C2 % d
    s2 = min(D, d - D)
    if s2 < s:
        s = s2
        C = C2
print(C, s)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я ввёл Ваш ответ, но почему-то он отметился как неверный. Очень странно.

Comment: @Daniil Savinov Не спешите с принятием ответов. Возможно, я тоже чего-то не учёл.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Только списывайте так, чтобы не понятно было

A, B, d = map(int,input().split())
s = 0 #Координата дома
k = 0 #Расстояние до киоска
if A > B:#Чтобы потом не маяться 
    A, B = B, A
if (B-A) % 2 == 0:#Четность
    s = A+(B-A)//2
    k = min(s%d, d-s%d)
else:
    s = A+(B-A)//2
    k = min(min(s%d,(s+1)%d),min(d-s%d, d-(s+1)%d))
    if (s+k)%d != 0 and (s-k)%d != 0:
        if(s+k+1)%d != 0:# Чтобы проходили отрицательные
            s-=1
        else:
            s+=1#Не за что  
print(s, k)
```